# How to Generate bit mask for a number from the number itself?

Tags: c

Is there any way with which I can generate bit mask of a number without changing the number itself?

I am new to programming and I have seen hard-coded bit-masks only.

Can we do any operations on the number to generate the bitmask, from the number itself (i.e.: a dynamically generated mask, depending the value of the number)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define the 'bit mask of a number'? It could be lots of things.

Comment: This is unfortunately very vague. Can you give a concrete example to what you're looking for? What will this bit mask be used for? For testing, for trimming, etc.?

Comment: A bitmask for what? Masks are used for filtering, so its format/structure depends on what your result should be, not what its inputs are.

Comment: What is a "number" in this case? An 16, 32, 64 bit integer? A 8 or 16 bit ASCII or Unicode character? A floating point format? [Perhaps reading a tutorial will help](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) Java and C and nearly the same btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not? Use the number itself as a mask:

```
//returns true if bit n is 1 and false otherwise
bool get(int index, int mask)
{
    return (mask >> index) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes Thank you @Oli Charlesworth!